# Finding a word after specific string - sql management studio 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have a text column with fields as per below (small sample, there are many variations):

```
INSERT INTO #retention1 VALUES ('hello Action=Refer non-action=non-refer')
INSERT INTO #retention1 VALUES ('bye Action=Follow non-action=non-refer')
INSERT INTO #retention1 VALUES ('hello non-action=non-refer Action=compare')
```

I need to find the word after "Action="
example ANSWER :
Entry 1: Refer
Entry 2: Follow
Entry 3: Compare

If all the words after "Action=" was the same length then I am able to do it. Unfortunately the length is unknown of all variations. The word after action is almost always different not only the 3 variations above.

Any ideas suggestions would be highly appreciated.

This is the code I used for the "Refer" example only which works:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @P_string nvarchar (100),
@P_variable    nvarchar (100)/*,
@P_return_null nvarchar(100) = 'Y'*/

set @p_string = 'hello Action=Refer non-action=non-refer'
set @p_variable = 'Action'

select substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string)) +len(@p_variable)+1,5) as trying


END;
```

Comment: Thank you for all the replies everyone!!! Much appreciated great solutions

Comment: there are thankyou buttons here on SO...

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking for should first look for the string `Action` and then for a space character after that word. After that you have all you need to manipulate your source string.

This should work:

```
DECLARE 
  @P_string nvarchar (100),
  @P_variable nvarchar (100),
  @idx1 int,
  @idx2 int

SET @p_string = 'hello Action=Refer non-action=non-refer'
SET @p_variable = 'Action'

SELECT
  @idx1 = charindex(lower(@P_variable),lower(@P_string)) + len(@p_variable) + 1,
  @idx2 = charindex(lower(' '), @P_string, @idx1) 

SELECT @idx1, @idx2

SELECT SUBSTRING(
  @p_string, 
  @idx1,
  @idx2 - @idx1) as trying
```

**EDIT**

After more thoroughly reviewing the requirements, I decided to tailor a rCTE structure that I use for similar purposes. Here it goes.

```
CREATE TABLE #retention1 (
  ID int,
  txt nvarchar (100)
)
INSERT INTO #retention1 VALUES (1, 'hello Action=Refer non-action=non-refer')
INSERT INTO #retention1 VALUES (2, 'bye Action=Follow non-action=non-refer')
INSERT INTO #retention1 VALUES (3, 'hello non-action=non-refer Action=compare')

;WITH T AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Row = 0,
    StartIdx = CAST(0 as int),
    EndIdx = CAST(0 as int),
    Result = CAST('' as nvarchar(max))
  FROM #retention1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    r1.ID,
    Row + 1,
    StartIdx = CAST(newstartidx AS int),
    EndIdx = CAST(EndIdx + newendidx as int),
    Result = CAST(newtoken as nvarchar(max))
  FROM 
    T
    JOIN #retention1 r1
      ON r1.ID = T.ID
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT newstartidx = EndIdx + 1
    ) calc1
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT newtxt = substring(r1.txt, newstartidx, len(r1.txt))
    ) calc2
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT patidx = charindex(' ', newtxt)
    ) calc3
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT newendidx = CASE 
        WHEN patidx = 0 THEN len(newtxt)
        ELSE patidx END
    ) calc4
    CROSS APPLY(
      SELECT newtoken = substring(r1.txt, newstartidx, newendidx)
    ) calc5
  WHERE newendidx > 0
) 
SELECT
  ID,
  --Result
  Name = left(Result, eqIdx - 1),
  Value = substring(Result, eqIdx + 1, len(Result) - eqIdx + 1)
FROM 
  T
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT eqIdx = charindex('=', Result)
  ) calc6
WHERE 
  Row != 0
  AND eqIdx != 0
ORDER BY ID
```

Since there are more than one expressions to parse in the table, you would have problems referencing them without an identifier. So, i added ID to your temporary table.

The output from CTE also contains ID which you can use as a reference to #retention1.ID.

Comment: This will fail for the third example `'hello non-action=non-refer Action=compare'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @ret nvarchar (100),@P_string nvarchar (100),
@P_variable    nvarchar (100)/*,
@P_return_null nvarchar(100) = 'Y'*/

set @p_string = 'hello Action=Refer non-action=non-refer'
set @p_variable = 'Action'

select @ret=substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string)) +len(@p_variable)+1,100) 

select substring(@ret,0,charindex(' ',lower(@ret),0))


END;
```

Comment: This will fail for the third example `'hello non-action=non-refer Action=compare'`

Answer (score 0):

String handling galore with a little cheating: Extending @p_string with a space at the begining and the end.

```
DECLARE @P_string nvarchar (100), @P_variable    nvarchar (100)

set @p_variable = ' Action='

set @p_string = ' hello Action=Refer non-action=non-refer '
select substring(substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string))+1, len(@p_string)-len(@p_variable)),charindex('=',substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string))+1, len(@p_string)-len(@p_variable)))+1,CHARINDEX(' ', substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string))+1, len(@p_string)-len(@p_variable)))-LEN(@P_variable))

set @p_string = ' bye Action=Follow non-action=non-refer '
select substring(substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string))+1, len(@p_string)-len(@p_variable)),charindex('=',substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string))+1, len(@p_string)-len(@p_variable)))+1,CHARINDEX(' ', substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string))+1, len(@p_string)-len(@p_variable)))-LEN(@P_variable))

set @p_string = ' hello non-action=non-refer Action=compare '
select substring(substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string))+1, len(@p_string)-len(@p_variable)),charindex('=',substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string))+1, len(@p_string)-len(@p_variable)))+1,CHARINDEX(' ', substring(@p_string, charindex(upper(@P_variable),upper(@P_string))+1, len(@p_string)-len(@p_variable)))-LEN(@P_variable))
```